# Error converting string to datetime due to locale

Tags: sql-server, datetime, date

I'm having a lot of difficulty with locale's in a particular instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

I'm in the UK and the following fails:

```
SELECT CAST('2012-12-31' AS DATETIME)
```

Error message:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

The Windows server locale is British English.  My login locale is British English.  Collation 'if that matters' is Latin1_General_CI_AS.

The database 'language' is English (United States) but then this is the same as another instance on a different server and the above SQL doesnt fail.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the user making the database connection -- the SQL user -- set the language to English.

This is a setting specific to the SQL user of the connection issuing the query

One way to check if this is a problem... Run this in Management Studio and login as the SQL user who issues the query

```
SET LANGUAGE English
SELECT CAST('2012-12-31' AS DATETIME)
```

If this works, set the default language of the SQL user appropriately

Comment: I don't agree that the solution is to make all users the same language. What if their language is set on purpose because it is being used for other things? Fixing each user is also tedious because every time a new user is created, the code may start failing just for them until you fix it. If you fix the code, you fix the problem.

Comment: This is not for all users.  This is for a SQL login account

Comment: Yeah, and when you add a new SQL login account and their language is set to British, guess what your code starts doing again?

Comment: I've never considered that.  Have always seen just a one or two SQL users, dedicated for our platform.  This is not an appropriate in your scenario.  However, this will get you "up and running" until the queries could be scrubbed and the product thoroughly tested.

Answer (score 7):

Don't use `YYYY-MM-DD` for date literals, always use `YYYYMMDD`. This will never fail, regardless of locale, dateformat settings, language settings, regional settings, etc:

```
SELECT CAST('20121231' AS DATETIME);
```

A worthwhile read perhaps:

- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: and what will happens when your user save a date as a  YYYYDDMM instead ? sql will never know and you'll end up with truckloads of errors very hard to pinpoint.

much safer to convert with date format as lamak said.

Comment: @Thierry When a user passes `'20121208'` as the unambiguous standard, and they meant August 12th instead of December 8th, the wrong date will be stored. If they pass `'20121612'` then they will receive an error. Those are the exact same things, by the way, that happen when your user passes `'2012-12-08'` to Lamak's method. The difference is that YYYYMMDD will *always* be interpreted that way by SQL Server, whereas YYYY-MM-DD will *sometimes* be interpreted the wrong way.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info. I'm asking because where I work, the regional setting is YYYYDDMM, because we enforce it to our clients, but the local setting by default its DDMMYYYY, and it often leads to confusions on dates.

Answer (score 4):

You should explicitly define the date format on your convert, in this case is 120:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'2012-12-31',120)
```

You can take a look at this page to see more date formats:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: The problem is this is supposed to be an exact replica of a live system.  The live setup actually does work and seemingly is the using same config.  I realise I can cast etc but I cant change the mirrored system.