# Is there a way to consistently convert a filename into a datetime value when the filename is somewhat "free form"?

Tags: c#, algorithm, parsing, datetime

Assuming the filename will always contain the date embedded within it, but that it won't be uniform, is there a way to parse such and consistently convert the filename into a DateTime?

More specifically, if the filename always has the same format, such as:

"NNNNN.YYYY-MM-DD.log"

...this is pretty easy.

But, if the filenames can be in any of the following formats:

"NNN.YYYY-MM-DD.log" or
"NNNNN.YYYY-MM-DD.txt" or
"NNNNNNN.YYYY-MM-DD.bunyan"
-- and maybe even:
"NNNNN.MM-DD-YYYY.xlw"
-and:
"NNNNN.YYYY-DD-MM.zsj"

-- IOW, the filenames always contain the date represented in some fashion, but otherwise, all bets are off, is there hope, or nope?

Comment: Will the MM-DD and DD-MM variants have known extensions?  Otherwise that's ambiguous.  Would 05-01 be May 1 or January 5?

Comment: Is there any more info here Clay?

Comment: I'm afraid the format is somewhat unpredictable. I guess I'll have to have the user specify the date separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no hope unless you can match an extension up to a known format.

Some days/month combinations you'll get lucky like 2012-12-31.  Clearly, 31 isn't the month value and you can deduce at least the day/month/4-digit year combo.

As Alexei mentioned, a 2 digit year further complicates the problem.

As a side note, this is pretty similar to a SQL Server problem.  This is fine and dandy until it's run with different date time format expectations:

`SELECT CAST('2012-05-01' AS DATETIME)`

Depending on the locale, this could be May 1, 2012 or January 5, 2012.
(See this thread: [Error converting string to datetime due to locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818796/error-converting-string-to-datetime-due-to-locale))

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible if you allow YYYY-DD-MM and YYYY-MM-DD pair or 2 digits for year.

What would be 10-11-12 (YY-DD-MM, DD-MM-YY,....)?

Answer (score 1):

split the string by `-` and loop through the list. 
if you see 3 consecutive numbers, then it's a possible hit. then parse those numbers to get a date. it's not going to catch all, but will catch most.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make *some* assumptions to get anywhere I think. All your examples are in the format NNN.SOMEDATEFORMAT.EXTENSION. DateTime.Parse is clever enough to handle most (all?) valid date/time formats. Try this;

```
string path = "123.2001-01-01.log";
string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
int indexFirstSeparator = filename.IndexOf('.') + 1;
string datepart = filename.Substring(indexFirstSeparator);
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(datepart);
```