# Is there a way to try to guess the date from a filename and, if unable, to gracefully fail?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, datepicker

I want to try to (programmatically) guess the date a file was created. It it is named *BlaBla.2012-06-04.xlw*, I can guess it was created June 4th, 2012.

However, if the file is named something else, like *SitOnA.PotatoPanOtis.pal*, I want to be able to simply give up (without the attempted conversion to a DateTime causing an exception) and present the user with a DateTimePicker.

Doable?

I've got this code:

```
String substr = SelectedFileName.Substring(DATE_BEGIN_POS, DATE_LENGTH);
return DateTime.Parse(substr);
```

I'm thinking something like this would make sense:

```
try 
{
    String substr = SelectedFileName.Substring(DATE_BEGIN_POS, DATE_LENGTH);
    return DateTime.Parse(substr);
}
catch (ConversionException ce) 
{
    //Show form with DateTimePicker
}
```

### UPDATE

It seems like something like this should work:

```
DateTime dt;
if (!(DateTime.TryParse(substr, out dt))) {
   . . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can ask directly for the creation time using the `File.GetCreationTime` or if you are trying to guess via the file name then you can use [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.tryparse%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for the date and if doesn't work (method return false) then show the dialog.

Answer (score 4):

don't guess. Get it !

```
var creationTime = File.GetCreationTime(@"c:\myfile.txt");
```

Comment: According to this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858574/is-there-a-way-to-consistently-convert-a-filename-into-a-datetime-value-when-the, I can't know the datetime from a file I retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

Use RegEx to match the filename.

```
Regex r = new Regex("\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}");
if (r.Match(fileName).Success) {
    //GUESS!
}
```

Comment: Will this work even if the order is different, such as "06-04-2012" instead of "2012-06-04"?

Comment: Then you must change the regex pattern. The pattern (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})|(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}) will match both date formats.

Comment: except you could never know for sure if it is dd-mm-yyyy or mm-dd-yyyy